# How to go from a static navbar to a position:fixed without screwing everything?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got problems when going from a normal navbar that just sits in the top side of the browser and disappears when you scroll down to a position:fixed navbar that stays at the top of the browser even when you scroll.

This is the codepen: https://codepen.io/bleah1/pen/gjYBgQ

The problem is that when I add position:fixed and top:0; left:0; right:0; to the .header-container it shrinks and moves the .navigation-bar lower and it pushes the .logo to the left, making it stick to the left side of the browser. I've tried changing some values but I still could not make it work and look good.

Also, the HTML is made kind of in reverse: first for the smaller window size, like phones or tablets and then for the bigger devices.

Full disclosure: These are not my ideas, I saw them on YouTube and I recreated them in an attempt to learn. These are the videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqbOu5ZRFag

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ah_Zitni1y4&

Do you have any idea on what to change to make it work ? Thank you !

```js
/*global $:false */
/*exported formValidationSetup, refreshErrorMessages */
 /*jshint unused:false*/


$('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
    $('.navigation-bar').toggleClass('navigation-bar--open', 500);
    $(this).toggleClass('menu-toggle--open');
});

$(".button").on("click",function(){
   $(".input").toggleClass("inclicked");
    $(".button").toggleClass("close");
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,700');


header{
    background-color: #1F2833;
    position: relative;
    color: #45A29E;
    padding: 1em 0;
}

header::after{
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    background-color: brown;
    margin:0 auto;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}


.header-container {
    position:fixed; /* This creates the problem*/
    width:95%; /*changing this to 100% does nothing */
    max-width: 1250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    backgrounnd-color:#1F2833;
   
}

.logo {
    color:#45A29E;
    float:left;
    font-size:1rem;
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
}



.navigation-bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0%;
    background-color: #1F2833;
    clip-path: circle(0px at top right);
    transition: clip-path ease-in-out 700ms;
}

.navigation-bar--open{
    clip-path: circle(150% at top right);
    
}


.navigation-bar ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    list-style: none;
}

.navigation-bar li{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C5C6C7;
}

.navigation-bar li:last-child{
    border-bottom: none;
}

.navigation-bar a{
    color: #45A29E;
    display: block;
    padding: 2em 3em 2em 1.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    
}

.navigation-bar a:hover,
.navigation-bar a:focus {
    background: #C5C6C7;
    color: #0B0C10;
}

.navigation-bar--icon{
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    width:1.3em;
    text-align: right;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.25);
}

.menu-toggle {
    
    padding: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.5em;
    right: 0.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.hamburger,
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    background: black;
    height: 3px;
    width: 1.75em;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition:  all ease-in-out 500ms;
}

.hamburger::before{
    transform: translateY(-6px);
}

.hamburger::after{
    transform: translateY(3px);
}

.menu-toggle--open .hamburger{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.menu-toggle--open .hamburger::before{
    opacity: 0;
}

.menu-toggle--open .hamburger::after{
    transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-90deg);
}

.search-container{
    display: none;
}

.cover{
  background: blue;
  height:300px;
  width:400px;
  
}

@media (min-width: 1250px){
    
    .menu-toggle {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .header-container{
        max-width: 1200px;
    }
    .navigation-bar {
        height: auto;
        position: relative;
        background: #1F2833;
        float:right;
        clip-path:initial;
    }
    .navigation-bar li{
        display: inline-block;
        border: none;
    }
    .navigation-bar a{
        padding:0;
        margin-left: 2em;
    }
    
    .navigation-bar a:hover,
    .navigation-bar a:focus {
        background:transparent;
        color: rgba(255,255,255,.25);
    }
    
    .navigation-bar--icon {
        display: none !important;
    }

    .search-container{
        display: inherit;
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        top:-5px;
        margin-left: 2em;
    }
    
}

.input{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 3px solid rgba(255,255,255,.25);
    box-sizing:border-box;
    outline:none;
    transition: width 600ms ease-in-out, border-radius 800ms ease-in-out, padding 200ms;
    transition-delay: 300ms;
    color:white;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.inclicked{
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 0 15px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}

.button{
    position: absolute;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    background:none;
    border:none;
    outline: none;
    cursor:pointer;
        
}

.button::before{
    content:'';
    width:3px;
    height:15px;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    bottom: -10px;
    right: -5px;
    transition:500ms;
    
}

.close::before, .close::after{
    content:'';
    width:3px;
    height: 20px;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,1);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    right: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    
}

.close::before{
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    
}
.close::after{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
       
}
    
}
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>
        
        <link href="navigation-bar.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="containers.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
        <title>Mangacious</title>
    
    </head>


<header>
    <div class="header-container">
        <h1 class="logo">Mangacius</h1>
        
        <div class="search-container search-container-2">
            <form class="search-box" action="index.html" method="post">
                <input class="input input-2" type="text" name="search">
                <button class="button" type="button" name="button"></button>
            </form>
        </div> <!--Little Browser Search Bar-->
        
        <nav class="navigation-bar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-home navigation-bar--icon"></i>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-calendar-check navigation-bar--icon"></i>Today's Uploads</a></li>
                <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-list-ol navigation-bar--icon"></i>Top 100</a></li>
                <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-store navigation-bar--icon"></i>Store</a></li>
                <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-th-list navigation-bar--icon"></i>My List</a></li>
                <li><a href=""><i class="fas fa-user-cog navigation-bar--icon"></i>User Control Panel</a></li>
            
            </ul>
        </nav> <!-- Navigation Bar -->
        
        
        <div class="menu-toggle">
            <div class="hamburger"></div>
        </div>
        
    </div><!-- Header Container --> 
    
</header>
    

<body>
   
    
    <div class="container new-releseas">
        <div class="cover"></div>
        <div class="cover"></div>
        <div class="cover"></div>
        <div class="cover"></div>
    </div><!-- New Releseas -->
    
    <div class="container must-reads">
    
    </div><!-- Must Reads -->
    
    <div class="container current-series">
    
    </div><!-- Current Series -->
    
    <div class="footer-container">
    
    </div><!-- Footer Container -->

    

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you update the snippet so we could see the **problem**? In the attached snippet everything looks good. Also, if you change from regular position (`static`) to `fixed` you have to set the width to `100%` (just like with position `absolute`)

Comment: Ok ! I've done that !

Comment: Also, there is another problem now. The background of the .header-container is transparent: the .logo and .search-container don't benefit from that background, they have transparent backgrounds.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Check the new Codepen link, I have fixed the `position` issue
https://codepen.io/nelh/pen/ejOPwE?editors=1100

Comment: https://codepen.io/bleah1/pen/gjYBgQ

I deleted the `header` from the css file but I don't have the same result as yours !
https://postimg.cc/image/amtr6ladd/

Comment: Also, as you can see in the image above the `.logo` is still acting like it has `left:0` and the `.search-container` acts like it has `right:0` .

Comment: @GeorgeFlorian your logo was acting like it has a left:0 because it had a margin-left:0px you just need to be careful because your code has been overwritten, by many property, so check the new pen and let me know if it works https://codepen.io/nelh/pen/ejOPwE?editors=1100